# How to get data from mongodb on basis of length of array inside mongo database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my mongoose activity schema.

```js
var Activity = new Schema({
    activityName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    activityPlace: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Virtual'
        },
        location: {
            type: {
                type: String,
                default: 'Point'
            },
            coordinates: {
                type: Array,
                default: [0, 0]
            }
        },
    },
    activityCategory: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    usersAttending: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }],
});
```

It has a field 'usersAttending'.
this is my function where i calling this mongo activity model.

```js
var getActivityNearbyFeed = function (location, distance, id, page, pagesize, callback) {
    var criteria = {
        "createdBy": {
            $ne: id
        },
        "activityPlace.location.coordinates": {
            $geoWithin: {
                $centerSphere: [
                    location.coordinates,
                    distance
                ]
            }
        },
    };

    var projection = {};

    var option = {
        lean: true
    }
    var query = Models.Activity.find(criteria, projection, option);
    query.skip(page * pagesize);
    query.limit(pagesize);
    //query.sort();
    query.exec(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, data);
        }
    })
};
```

I want to get the data sorted on the basis of the length of the array usersAttending. i am getting the data in the query object, is there any way through which i can get data inside in that object sorted on the basis of length of usersAttending array. i have used the sort function but unable to find correct syntax for it. thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the aggregation framework for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort documents based on length of an Array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063941/how-to-sort-documents-based-on-length-of-an-array-field)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that directly. The simplest answer would be to maintain a `length` variable that you use to keep track of the array length, incrementing it every time the insertion is done in the array and decrementing for deletion.

Another way of doing it is by using the `.aggregate()` method as described at [How to sort documents based on length of an Array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063941/how-to-sort-documents-based-on-length-of-an-array-field). Though for your query it would be quite complex to write indeed.